# Postgres join not respecting outer where clause

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server, I know for sure that the following query;

```
SELECT things.*
FROM things
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  thingreadings.thingid, reading 
    FROM thingreadings 
    INNER JOIN things on thingreadings.thingid = things.id 
    ORDER BY reading DESC LIMIT 1) AS readings

ON things.id = readings.thingid 
WHERE things.id = '1'
```

Would join against `thingreadings` only once the `WHERE id = 1` had restricted the record set down. It left joins against just one row. However in order for performance to be acceptable in postgres, I have to add the `WHERE id= 1` to the `INNER JOIN things on thingreadings.thingid = things.id` line too.

This isn't ideal; is it possible to force postgres to know that what I am joining against is only one row without explicitly adding the `WHERE` clauses everywhere?

An example of this problem can be seen here;

I am trying to recreate the following query in a more efficient way;

```
SELECT things.id, things.name,
(SELECT thingreadings.id      FROM thingreadings WHERE thingid = things.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),
(SELECT thingreadings.reading FROM thingreadings WHERE thingid = things.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

FROM things
WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a172c/2

Comment: What is your actual use case? This looks like a very roundabout way of saying "For this specific <thing> give me up to one <thingreading>".

Comment: Yes the use case is for one <thing>, give me the id and the reading of the *most recent* <thingreading>. THe super trivial way of doing it would be 2 sub selects but I was trying to do it without 2 subselects.

Comment: Which version of postgres are you using? 9.3 introduced lateral joins which (though a bit strange at first) are great for this type of situation. The way your query is currently written, the query in the left join will only return one row for all things, which might not even be the thingreading on the thing you're looking for. If you can't use a lateral join, I'd probably either stick with a subquery in the select list or revise the subquery in the join clause to give the most recent thingreading for every thing.

Comment: Also, depending on your particular situation, two queries might not be so bad here - one for the <thing> and another for the most recent <thingreading> given the thing's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why you did all that work. Isn't the inner query enough?

```
SELECT  t.* 
FROM thingreadings tr 
INNER JOIN things t on tr.thingid = t.id AND t.id = '1'
ORDER BY tr.reading DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b057a/1)</kbd>

When you want to select the latest value for each thingID, you can do:

```
SELECT t.*,a.reading 
FROM things t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT t1.*
  FROM thingreadings t1
    LEFT JOIN thingreadings t2
      ON (t1.thingid = t2.thingid AND t1.reading < t2.reading)
  WHERE t2.thingid IS NULL
) a ON a.thingid = t.id
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b057a/15)</kbd>

The derived table gets you the record with the most recent reading, then the JOIN gets you the information from things table for that record.

Comment: No I am trying to get the most recent reading, this query would give me one row for every reading I have.

Comment: No. This will give you the most recent reading for that t.id (the ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 make sure of that). Maybe you can explain a little better what you want, if this isn't it.

Comment: That will not work if I am pulling back more than one thing. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b057a/10 is what I am trying to emulate but without 2 subselects.

Comment: Ok. That is true. See if this is what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b057a/15

Comment: That's clever, hadn't thought about that approach before. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause in SQL applies to the result set you're requesting, NOT to the join.

What your code is NOT saying: "do this join only for the ID of 1"...

What your code IS saying: "do this join, then pull records out of it where the ID is 1"...

This is why you need the inner where clause. Incidentally, I also think Filipe is right about the unnecessary code.